# Perl Regex: Match all folders except a certain subfolder pattern

Tags: regex, perl

Given these folder names:

```
locales/DE/en    
locales/FR/en
locales/US/en
locales/US/fr
public
test
[...]
```

I want to match everything EXCEPT the first 2 patterns. There are other folders in the root, and other subfolders in the `locales` folder. I really want to just exclude everything in `locales/*` EXCEPT `locales/US`

This works for `locales` but fails to include the other root folders.
`/(locales)\/(US)/`

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you allow everything, use `^.*$` and restrict it with a lookahead disallowing the `locales/(?:DE|FR)` at the beginning: [`/^(?!locales\/(?:DE|FR)).*$/`](https://regex101.com/r/vF1fZ3/3).

Answer (score 4):

To match anything EXCEPT `locales/US`, you can use negative lookahead:

```
/^(?!locales\/US).*/m
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rO4jD0/1)

Comment: I believe he wants to skip every file in locale i.e `locales/*` except `locale/US`.

Comment: Based on this line in question `This works for locales but fails to include the other root folders.` I think OP wants to exclude `locales/US` only

Comment: His regex works for `locales`, so he is talking about `public`, `test` as other root folders.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two regular expressions instead of cluttering it up in one. Below is an attempt:

```
my @folders =
  qw (locales/DE/en locales/FR/en locales/US/en locales/US/fr public test);

foreach (@folders) {
    if (/^locales/) {
        next if ( $_ !~ /^locales\/US/ ); # skip everything except locales/US
    }
    print $_,"\n";
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but the point of a regex is to remove verbosity. You want to define a rule and apply it in one line.